# "Tie on" vs. "Tie to"

Tags: prepositions, difference

Initially, the verb *Tie* means to fasten something on something, but what would be the proper preposition to use after *Tie*?

I've made a search but I couldn't find anything, what is the difference between these two terms? Could anyone provide me some examples and explain what differs them?

Comment: It depends:  Tie a knot *in* a rope - Tie a yellow ribbon *around* the old oak tree - Tie your boat *to* the dock - Tie a fly *on* your fishing pole.

Comment: What kind of search did you make?  [Try this one](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=tie_VERB+*_ADP&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Ctie_VERB%20%2A_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20on_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20in_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20with_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20into_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20round_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20around_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20about_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20at_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20over_ADP%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Btie_VERB%20for_ADP%3B%2Cc0)

Answer (score 1):

From a native speaker:

Tie can take many prepositions.  '**Tie on**' is more physical ... to 'tie one on' is to get drunk (perhaps related to hanging, like the morning hangover).

'**Tie to**' is to more abstract a connection, so your question is *tied to* (somewhat connected to) the differences that a little preposition can have on the meaning of the sentence.

'**Tie someone up**' means put ropes on their body.  In the abstract, it means to confine them or involve them in something unwanted: "I am in a rush, and you want to **tie me up** with a long conversation."